# mysql + .NET connector : "Column 'CharacterID' cannot be null"

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert some data into my MySql Database using the .NET connector.

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spr_StoreMoveData2`(IN `@characterID` INT, IN `@moveName` VARCHAR(1000), IN `@validBlocks` VARCHAR(50), IN `@damage` VARCHAR(500), IN `@stun` VARCHAR(500), IN `@cancelAbility` VARCHAR(50), IN `@framesStartup` VARCHAR(500), IN `@framesActive` VARCHAR(500), IN `@framesRecovery` VARCHAR(500), IN `@framesAdvOnHit` VARCHAR(500), IN `@framesAdvOnBlock` VARCHAR(500), IN `@additionalNotes` VARCHAR(5000))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'test'
BEGIN
INSERT INTO movedata 
(characterid, movename, validblocks, damage, stun, supermetergain,cancelability, framesStartup, framesActive, framesRecovery, framesAdvOnHit, framesAdvOnBlock, AdditionalNotes) 
VALUES 
(@characterID, @moveName, @validBlocks, @damage, @stun, @superMeterGain, @cancelAbility, @framesStartup, @framesActive, @framesRecovery, @framesAdvOnHit, @framesAdvOnBlock, @additionalNotes);
END
```

Which appears to save fine.

My .NET code is as follows:

```
 using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();
                    conn.Open();

                    MoveData move1 = lmd[0];

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("spr_StoreMoveData", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CharacterID", move1.CharacterID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("movename", move1.MoveName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("validblocks", move1.ValidBlocks);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("damage", move1.Damage);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("stun", move1.Stun);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("supermetergain", move1.SuperMeterGain);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cancelability", move1.CancelAbility);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("framesstartup", move1.Frames_Startup);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("framesactive", move1.Frames_Active);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("framesrecovery", move1.Frames_Recovery);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("framesAdvOnHit", move1.Frames_AdvantageOnHit);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("framesAdvOnBlock", move1.Frames_AdvantageOnBlock);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("additionalNotes", move1.AdditionalNotes);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cmd = null;
                }
```

If I use this, or if I use the following test query

```
call spr_StoreMoveData (1, '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
```

The error **"Column 'CharacterID' cannot be null"** appears. I set the columns to allow null values and a row will be inserted with all null values. I'm slightly perplexed.

I've tried looking at all the answers on the web, but I appear to be missing some syntax subtlety. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement uses `@superMeterGain`, which your procedure does not have as a parameter. So you are setting, and using, a parameter which your procedure does not know. Add it to the list of parameters of your stored procedure, and it should work.

Comment: I apologise - this is what I get for writing the question just before bed... I've doubled checked the spellings on all parameters and the error "Column 'CharacterID' cannot be null" still appears. I've read snippets that mySQL treats @ as server side variables, could this be the problem? I've tried swapping @ for ? but HeidiSQL doesn't let me save, so I'm assuming that isn't valid mySQL syntax...